# Google Sites - JDBC to Azure SQL DB

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a SQL database with Microsoft Azure that I want to connect my Google App Scripts to for viewing or altering data. So far I have had success with using the JDBC connection with sheet scripts, however I am running into an issue when I run the same script on a site script. I have tried writing it in the 'Code.gs' file and then calling it in my HTML file with 'google.script.run'. I've tried just writing it as a javascript function within the HTML file itself, but still no bueno. Seems as if there is a library that is missing or reference that is not in sites as in sheets. Any ideas? Here's the code for review:

```
// Gets data from the external database
// Same function used in both sheets and sites
function getStores() { 
    conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://azureDB.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=dbName",
        "userName", "password");
    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    var result = stmt.executeQuery("select something from somethingElse");

    var resArray = result.getArray(1);
    return resArray;
}

// Loads the collected data into the <option> elements of a <select> element
// Currently throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined' in Chrome Console
function loadStores() {
     var resArray = getStores();
     var eleSelectElement = document.getElementById('SelectElement');
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < retArray.length; i++)
     {
         var option = document.createElement('option');
         option.text = 'Value: ' + resArray [i];
         option.value = resArray [i];
         eleSelectElement.add(option);
     }
 }

// Loads the collected data into the first column of the spreadsheet
// Works as expected
function loadSheet() {      
     var resArray = getStores();
     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UID/edit');
     var cell = doc.getRange('a1');

     for (var i = 0; i < resArray.length; i++)
         cell.offset(i,0).setValue(resArray[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why, but I ended up having to make Google Apps Script Web App and then embeded into the website. Now everything works fine. The only issue here is that I can't read information about that current sessions of the website (ex. current user, etc.).